# Kotlin: Java Util Date to String for Databindings

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I want to use the Date value of my Data class in view via Databinding.
If I use the toString() method on the Date field it works. But I want to customize the Date value. 
So I created the Utils object with Method. This is the Util object

```
object DateUtils {

     fun toSimpleString(date: Date) : String {
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy")
        return format.format(date)
    }
}
```

But if I want to use this method in the xml like this

```
<data>
    <import type="de.mjkd.journeylogger.Utils.DateUtils"/>

    <variable
        name="journey"
        type="de.mjkd.journeylogger.data.Journey"/>
</data>
...
    android:text="@{DateUtils.toSimpleString(journey.date)}"
```

I get an error `cannot find method toSimpleString(java.util.Date) in class ...`

This is my Dataclass:

```
data class Journey(var title: String, var date: Date?, var destination: String)
```

Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: one problem is for sure that journey.date is nullable and toSimpleString accepts only a non-nullable Date.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using the reserved word **object** in kotlin, that you really doing is declare a single instance. the equivalent in java is something more or less like:

```
class DataUtils {
    static DataUtils INSTANCE;
    public String toSimpleString()...
}
```

then when you call it you do a `DateUtils.INSTANCE.toSimpleString()`

You should capable to use `DateUtils.INSTANCE.toSimpleString()` in your xml

---

In order to make `toSimpleString` accessible from static context, you have to flag the method with`@JvmStatic`

```
object DateUtils {
    @JvmStatic
    fun toSimpleString(date: Date) : String {
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy")
        return format.format(date)
    }
}
```

**Using extension function**([doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html))

```
@file:JvmName("DateUtils")//Use this to change your class name in java, by default is <the file name>Kt (DateUtilsKt in your case)

fun Date.toSimpleString() : String {
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy")
    return format.format(this)
}
```

Then you can use it directly in xml as you are already doing:

```
android:text="@{DateUtils.toSimpleString(journey.date)}"
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I have tried the  Extension Function and called it in the xml like this `android:text="@{journey.date.toSimpleString())`but this did not work. How do i call the extension Function from the xml?

Comment: @Kevin Xml does use the java syntax to resolve the code, you have to use it as static funtion as described in the end of my answer, read [this doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) for more understanding

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a top-level function which is static by default? A top-level function is not defined in any class.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    println(toSimpleString(Date())) 
}

fun toSimpleString(date: Date?) = with(date ?: Date()) {
    SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").format(this)
}
```

Also, notice how Jouney's date is nullable in your example and your `toSimpleString` only accepts a non-nullable Date!

I changed it, so that it will return the string of the current date in case null is passed.

Answer (score 0):

**More easy way** would be to make a `getDateString` in model class.

```
android:text="@{journey.dateString)}"

class Journey {
    lateinit var date: Date
    fun getDateString(){
        return DataUtils.toSimpleString(date)
    }
}
```

I like this way because I don't need to import any class in this case.

Comment: Then you have to write 10 times of the same method if you have 10 model classes (if they all have `Date` property).